# Possible to decompose a directed-graph into a list?

Tags: graph, etl, directed-acyclic-graphs

This is more a theoretical question, but for a [DAG](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dags/) is it possible to condense this down into a list of operations? Or is this a data structure that cannot be broken down into a flat list in the order of something like:

```
STEPS = [
    filter A to country = 'US',
    (join A to B on A.id=B.id) AS c,
    filter C to...
]
```

Would it be possible to construct a DAG that cannot be decomposed without losing information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a directed acyclic graph (DAG) can be condensed into an *ordered* list of operations, ***if***, in fact, the DAG represents data flowing through operations.  That is, an ordered list of assignment statements and function calls can be expressed as a DAG, and vice versa.

A DAG for the above example might look like

```
+-----+     +-------------+
|     |  A  |   filter I1 | A'
|  A  |-----|1  to country|---+                    
|     |     |       ='US' |   |                                           
+-----+     +-------------+   |  +--------------+   +-----------+   +----------+
                              +--|1  join I1 to | C |   filter  | C'|   Result |
                                 |   I2 on I1.id|---|1  I1 to...|---|1    = I1 |
                              +--|2      = I2.id|   |           |   |          |
                  +-------+   |  +--------------+   +------- ---+   +----------+
                  |       | B |                                  
                  |   B   |---+
                  |       |
                  +-------+
```

Alternatively, the "list of operations" could be thought of as nested functions calls, evaluated from most deeply nested to least deeply nested.  For example,

```
Result = Fn3( Fn2( Fn1(A), B ) ).
```

The DAG is the same, as redrawn here without showing intermediate variables and with simplified function names.

```
+-----+     +-------------+
|     |     |             |
|  A  |-----|1    Fn1     |---+                    
|     |     |             |   |                                        
+-----+     +-------------+   |  +--------------+   +-----------+   +----------+
                              +--|1             |   |           |   |          |
                                 |      Fn2     |---|1   Fn3    |---|1  Result |
                              +--|2             |   |           |   |          |
                  +-------+   |  +--------------+   +------- ---+   +----------+
                  |       |   |                                  
                  |   B   |---+
                  |       |
                  +-------+
```

I'm not aware of any situation in which information would be lost upon decomposition from DAG to "list of operations".  The two forms are equivalent to each other.

---

A practical example of how to construct DAGs to represent lists of operations can be found in [IEC 61131-3:2013](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/4552), which "specifies syntax and semantics of programming languages for programmable controllers..."  That standard calls the DAG a network, defined as "a maximal set of interconnected graphic elements" (in the context of a partially ordered set) and presents evaluation rules, including the rule that "No element of a network shall be evaluated until the states of all of its inputs have been evaluated."  That rule provides the basis for order of operations.

Comment: great answer. In practical applications, such as Informatica or something -- do they use multiple processes/threads when there can be multiple inputs? Or is usually a single process?